# How to check wsdl is working or not using php soap client

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am having following api which is based on wsdl

**http://api.testdomain.com/services/TestService?wsdl**

The above API is now working for most of the time so I need to check whether the API is connected whenever I open my website. I Tried following piece of code

```
$client = new SoapClient("api.testdomain.com/services/TestService?wsdl", array('exceptions' => 0));

if (is_soap_fault($client)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo 'con';
}
```

But always getting error as

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity `"api.testdomain.com/services/TestService?wsdl`"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `http://` prefix to the URL in SoapClient().